# Proposition 11 (Chapter 1, Section 5) in Lang's Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

We state the proposition mentioned in the title:

**Proposition 1.** Let $A$ be an integral domain with fraction field $K.$

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension with group $G.$

Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L.$

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a maximal ideal of $A$ and let $\mathfrak{P}$ and $\mathfrak{Q}$ be two prime ideals of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}.$

Then there exists $\sigma \in G$ such that $\mathfrak{P}=\sigma\mathfrak{Q}.$

---

I follow Lang's proof of this result but after the proof he remarks that, by localizing, one can reduce the hypothesis that $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal to the hypothesis that $\mathfrak{p}$ is merely prime. This kind of argument pops up a lot in the books I read ("By localizing, we may as well assume $A$ is local" etc) and I'm not very comfortable with it so I've tried to work out the details in this case.

I would be very grateful if someone could check whether I've done this correctly.

---

Let's assume the result of Proposition 1.

Let Proposition 2 from Proposition 1 be obtained by replacing "$\mathfrak{p}$ be a maximal'' with "$\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime''

**Proof of Proposition 2.** Localizing at $\mathfrak{p},$ we get

$\bullet$ $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain with fraction field $K$ (obvious).

$\bullet$ $B_\mathfrak{p}$ is the integral closure of $A_\mathfrak{p}$ in $L$ as localization commutes with integral closures.

We also have that

$\bullet$ $\mathfrak{P}\cap (A\setminus \mathfrak{p})=\emptyset$ as $\mathfrak{P}\cap (A\setminus \mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{P}\cap (A \cap (A\setminus \mathfrak{p}))=(\mathfrak{P}\cap A) \cap (A\setminus \mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{p}\cap (A\setminus \mathfrak{p})$.

$\bullet$ $\mathfrak{Q}\cap (A\setminus \mathfrak{p})=\emptyset$ (same as for $\mathfrak{P}$).

Hence $\mathfrak{P}_\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{Q}_\mathfrak{p}$ are prime ideals of $B_\mathfrak{p}$ (by the correspondence of prime ideals wrt localization).

Moreover, we have $\mathfrak{P}_\mathfrak{p}\cap A_\mathfrak{p}=(\mathfrak{P}\cap A)_\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p}$ (as localization commutes with finite intersections).

Similarly, we have $\mathfrak{Q}_\mathfrak{p}\cap A_\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p}.$

Hence, as $\mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal in $A_\mathfrak{p},$ we apply Prop. 1 (with $A,B,\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{P},\mathfrak{Q}$ replaced by their localizations).

Thus there exists some $\sigma \in G$ such that $\mathfrak{P}_\mathfrak{p}=\sigma\mathfrak{Q}_\mathfrak{p}.$

*Claim:* $\mathfrak{P}=\sigma\mathfrak{Q}.$

*Proof of Claim:* Let $y \in \mathfrak{Q}$ be given. Then $y \in \mathfrak{Q}_\mathfrak{p}$ and so $\sigma(y) \in \mathfrak{P}_\mathfrak{p}.$

Thus $\sigma(y)=x/s$ for some $x \in \mathfrak{P}$ and $s \in A\setminus\mathfrak{p}$ and so $\sigma(y)s\in \mathfrak{P}.$

As $s\notin \mathfrak{P}$ and $\mathfrak{P}$ is prime, we have $\sigma(y) \in \mathfrak{P}.$

Conversely, let $x \in \mathfrak{P}$ be given. Then $x=\sigma(y/s)$ for some $y \in \mathfrak{Q}$ and $s \in A\setminus\mathfrak{p}.$

Since $\sigma(s)=s,$ we have $sx=\sigma(y)\in\sigma\mathfrak{Q}.$

As before, we conclude that $x \in \sigma\mathfrak{Q}.$ $\;$ Q.E.D.

Comment: Well done, this looks good. You can see clearly where you use the prime hypothesis and how the localization argument comes in.