# Problem Related to an Earlier Question

Tags: commutative-algebra

The following question has been already asked on this site before here-
[Proposition 11 (Chapter 1, Section 5) in Lang's Algebraic Number Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946594/proposition-11-chapter-1-section-5-in-langs-algebraic-number-theory?rq=1).
I now want to generalize this statement for infinite Galois extensions using Zorn's Lemma. Can anybody please help me with this? As I have no exposure to infinite Galois Theory, a detailed proof will be most helpful in this case. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It'd be good if your question was self contained and the title actually said something about it.

Comment: I thought  nobody would face trouble in understanding the question after I have cited the referrence.

Comment: It's not about understanding the question, it's about making it easy for people to know what you're asking. The first problem is that the title says *nothing* about the question. People usually like to answer questions on certain specific topics, so it's a good idea to write a title that attracts people. Furthermore, I think a lot of users (me included in this case) won't go through the trouble of opening a link when quickly taking a look in here.